# Oracle PLS 00103 error for procedure while executing it

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have below procedure giving me error as

> Error(17,3): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FOR" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null select with          continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute fora

Here is the procedure.

```html
PROCEDURE DeactiveUsers (
      P_DeactiveUsers_OUT      OUT SYS_REFCURSOR ) AS
  BEGIN
  
       
        
   OPEN P_DeactiveUsers_OUT FOR
  for P_DeactiveUsers_Lst in(
    select * from (    
        select username, MAX(TRANSACTION_DATE) As last_login_date 
        from r4g_application_activity_log
        Group By username
    ) where last_login_date <= sysdate-90
    order by 2 desc
  )
  
  update r4g_application_activity_log
  set ISACTIVE = 1
  where USERNAME = P_DeactiveUsers_OUT.username;
         
    EXCEPTION 
    WHEN no_data_found THEN 
    INS_UMS_ERRORLOG(SQLCODE||' : '||SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200),null,'DeactiveUsers',null,null,null,'DB : DeactiveUsers','Scheduler - UMS_DeactiveUser');
    WHEN others THEN 
    INS_UMS_ERRORLOG(SQLCODE||' : '||SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200),null,'DeactiveUsers',null,null,null,'DB : DeactiveUsers','Scheduler - UMS_DeactiveUser');
  END DeactiveUsers;
```

Comment: You have an error procedure, and What do you need? Code in that proc seem unreadable with unknown syntax. Open cursor for nothing, loop with nature language syntax instead of pl/sql syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, yes - procedure is here, but - what is its purpose? The way you put it, it seems that it shouldn't return anything so you don't really want to open a ref cursor, but use a cursor `FOR` loop which then updates the log table.

If that's so,

- remove `OUT` parameter
- remove `OPEN` clause (btw. you've got two `FOR`s)
- use `FOR` loop
- remove `WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND` as there's nothing that could raise it

---

```
PROCEDURE DeactiveUsers             -- (P_DeactiveUsers_OUT OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
   --OPEN P_DeactiveUsers_OUT FOR
   FOR P_DeactiveUsers_Lst
      IN (  SELECT *
              FROM (  SELECT username, MAX (TRANSACTION_DATE) AS last_login_date
                        FROM r4g_application_activity_log
                    GROUP BY username)
             WHERE last_login_date <= SYSDATE - 90
          ORDER BY 2 DESC)
   LOOP
      UPDATE r4g_application_activity_log
         SET ISACTIVE = 1
       WHERE USERNAME = P_DeactiveUsers_OUT.username;
   END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
   --    WHEN no_data_found THEN
   --    INS_UMS_ERRORLOG(SQLCODE||' : '||SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200),null,'DeactiveUsers',null,null,null,'DB : DeactiveUsers','Scheduler - UMS_DeactiveUser');
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      INS_UMS_ERRORLOG (SQLCODE || ' : ' || SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 200),
                        NULL,
                        'DeactiveUsers',
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        'DB : DeactiveUsers',
                        'Scheduler - UMS_DeactiveUser');
END DeactiveUsers;
```

---

**[EDIT]**

As you want to return list of deactivated users, then you could do it as follows: instead of a ref cursor, just loop through result set, do the update and return a collection of deactivated users:

```
PROCEDURE deactiveusers (p_deactivataed OUT SYS.odcivarchar2list)
IS
   l_deactivated  SYS.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list ();
BEGIN
   FOR cur_r
      IN (  SELECT *
              FROM (  SELECT username, MAX (TRANSACTION_DATE) AS last_login_date
                        FROM r4g_application_activity_log
                    GROUP BY username)
             WHERE last_login_date <= SYSDATE - 90
          ORDER BY 2 DESC)
   LOOP
      UPDATE r4g_application_activity_log
         SET isactive = 1
       WHERE username = cur_r.username;

      l_deactivated.EXTEND;
      l_deactivated (l_deactivated.LAST) := cur_r.username;
   END LOOP;

   p_deactivated := l_deactivated;
END;
```

You'd call it as e.g.

```
DECLARE
   l_deactivated  SYS.odcivarchar2list;
BEGIN
   deactiveusers (l_deactivated);

   FOR i IN l_deactivated.FIRST .. l_deactivated.LAST
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_deactivated (i));
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Have a look at edited answer.